# Re-queue message on exception

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, publish-subscribe, easynetq

I'm looking for a solid way of re-queuing messages that couldn't be handled properly - at this time.

I've been looking at http://dotnetcodr.com/2014/06/16/rabbitmq-in-net-c-basic-error-handling-in-receiver/ and it seems that it's supported to requeue messages in the RabbitMQ API.

```
else //reject the message but push back to queue for later re-try
{
    Console.WriteLine("Rejecting message and putting it back to the queue: {0}", message);
    model.BasicReject(deliveryArguments.DeliveryTag, true);
}
```

However I'm using EasyNetQ.
So wondering how I would do something similar here.

```
bus.Subscribe<MyMessage>("my_subscription_id", msg => {
    try
    {
        // do work... could be long running
    }
    catch ()
    {
        // something went wrong - requeue message
    }
});
```

Is this even a good approach? Not `ACK` the message could cause problems if `do work` exceeds the wait for `ACK` timeout by the RabbitMQ server.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So I came up with this solution. Which replaces the default error strategy by EasyNetQ.

```
public class DeadLetterStrategy : DefaultConsumerErrorStrategy
{
    public DeadLetterStrategy(IConnectionFactory connectionFactory, ISerializer serializer, IEasyNetQLogger logger, IConventions conventions, ITypeNameSerializer typeNameSerializer)
    : base(connectionFactory, serializer, logger, conventions, typeNameSerializer)
    {
    }

    public override AckStrategy HandleConsumerError(ConsumerExecutionContext context, Exception exception)
    {
        object deathHeaderObject;
        if (!context.Properties.Headers.TryGetValue("x-death", out deathHeaderObject))
            return AckStrategies.NackWithoutRequeue;

        var deathHeaders = deathHeaderObject as IList;

        if (deathHeaders == null)
            return AckStrategies.NackWithoutRequeue;

        var retries = 0;
        foreach (IDictionary header in deathHeaders)
        {
            var count = int.Parse(header["count"].ToString());
            retries += count;
        }

        if (retries < 3)
            return AckStrategies.NackWithoutRequeue;
        return base.HandleConsumerError(context, exception);
    }
}
```

You replace it like this:

```
RabbitHutch.CreateBus("host=localhost", serviceRegister => serviceRegister.Register<IConsumerErrorStrategy, DeadLetterStrategy>())
```

You have to use the `AdvancedBus` so you have to setup everything up manually.

```
using (var bus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus("host=localhost", serviceRegister => serviceRegister.Register<IConsumerErrorStrategy, DeadLetterStrategy>()))
{
    var deadExchange = bus.Advanced.ExchangeDeclare("exchange.text.dead", ExchangeType.Direct);
    var textExchange = bus.Advanced.ExchangeDeclare("exchange.text", ExchangeType.Direct);
    var queue = bus.Advanced.QueueDeclare("queue.text", deadLetterExchange: deadExchange.Name);
    bus.Advanced.Bind(deadExchange, queue, "");
    bus.Advanced.Bind(textExchange, queue, "");

    bus.Advanced.Consume<TextMessage>(queue, (message, info) => HandleTextMessage(message, info));
}
```

This will dead letter a failed message 3 times. After that it'll go to the default error queue provided by EasyNetQ for error handling. *You can subscribe to that queue.*

A message is dead lettered when an exception propagates out of your consumer method. So this would trigger a dead letter.

```
static void HandleTextMessage(IMessage<TextMessage> textMessage, MessageReceivedInfo info)
{
    throw new Exception("This is a test!");
}
```

Comment: Looking on implementation your DeadLetterStrategy there is no delay between resubmitting message to queue. I'd like to have some running delay between next resubmit like 2*t seconds delay (common strategy that delays time by multiplying by some factor like 2). Can this be done without Thread.Sleep?

Answer (score 4):

to the best of my knowledge, there is no way to manually `ack`, `nack` or `reject` a message with EasyNetQ.

I see you have [opened an issue ticket with the EasyNetQ team](https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/issues), regarding this... but no answer, yet.

FWIW, this is a very appropriate thing to do. All of the libraries that I use support this feature set (in NodeJS) and it is common. I'm surprised EasyNetQ doesn't support this.

Comment: Seems I have to fallback on RabbitMQ.Client if I want this functionality