# EasyNetQ - How to retry failed messages & persist RetryCount in message body/header?

Tags: c#, error-handling, rabbitmq, message-queue, easynetq

I am using EasyNetQ and need to retry failed messages on the original queue. The problem is: even though I successfully increment the TriedCount variable (in the body of every msg), when EasyNetQ publishes the message to the default error queue after an exception, the updated TriedCount is not in the msg! Presumably because it just dumps the original message to the error queue without the consumer's changes.

The updated TriedCount works for in-process republishes, but not when republished through EasyNetQ Hosepipe or EasyNetQ Management Client. The text files [Hosepipe](https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/wiki/Re-Submitting-Error-Messages-With-EasyNetQ.Hosepipe) generates do not have the TriedCount updated.

```
public interface IMsgHandler<T> where T: class, IMessageType
{
    Task InvokeMsgCallbackFunc(T msg);
    Func<T, Task> MsgCallbackFunc { get; set; }
    bool IsTryValid(T msg, string refSubscriptionId); // Calls callback only 
                                                      // if Retry is valid
}

public interface IMessageType
{
    int MsgTypeId { get; }

    Dictionary<string, TryInfo> MsgTryInfo {get; set;}

}

public class TryInfo
{   
    public int TriedCount { get; set; }

    /*Other information regarding msg attempt*/
}

public bool SubscribeAsync<T>(Func<T, Task> eventHandler, string subscriptionId)
{
    IMsgHandler<T> currMsgHandler = new MsgHandler<T>(eventHandler, subscriptionId);
    // Using the msgHandler allows to add a mediator between EasyNetQ and the actual callback function
    // The mediator can transmit the retried msg or choose to ignore it
    return _defaultBus.SubscribeAsync<T>(subscriptionId, currMsgHandler.InvokeMsgCallbackFunc).Queue != null;
}
```

I have also tried republishing myself through the [Management API](https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/wiki/Management-API-Introduction) (rough code):

```
var client = new ManagementClient("http://localhost", "guest", "guest");
var vhost = client.GetVhostAsync("/").Result;
var errQueue = client.GetQueueAsync("EasyNetQ_Default_Error_Queue", 
vhost).Result;
var crit = new GetMessagesCriteria(long.MaxValue, 
Ackmodes.ack_requeue_true);
var errMsgs = client.GetMessagesFromQueueAsync(errQueue, 
crit).Result;

foreach (var errMsg in errMsgs)
{
    var pubRes = client.PublishAsync(client.GetExchangeAsync(errMsg.Exchange, vhost).Result,
                                 new PublishInfo(errMsg.RoutingKey, errMsg.Payload)).Result;
        }
```

This works but only publishes to the error queue again, not on the original queue. Also, I don't know how to add/update the retry information in the body of the message at this stage.

I have explored [this](https://github.com/Matthew-Davey/EasyNetQ.MetaData) library to add headers to the message but I don't see if the count in the body is not being updated, how/why would the count in the header be updated.

Is there any way to persist the TriedCount without resorting to the Advanced bus (in which case I might use the RabbitMQ .Net client itself)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just in case it helps someone else, I eventually implemented my own [IErrorMessageSerializer](https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/blob/1c5d35c26b2abe87f331340e163c91715e704554/Source/EasyNetQ/Consumer/IErrorMessageSerializer.cs) (as opposed to implementing the whole [IConsumerErrorStrategy](https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/blob/1c5d35c26b2abe87f331340e163c91715e704554/Source/EasyNetQ/Consumer/IConsumerErrorStrategy.cs), which seemed like an overkill). The reason I am adding the retry info in the body (instead of the header) is that EasyNetQ doesn't handle complex types in the header (not out-of-the-box anyway). So, using a dictionary gives more control for different consumers. I register the custom serializer at the time of creating the bus like so:

```
_defaultBus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus(currentConnString, serviceRegister => serviceRegister.Register<IErrorMessageSerializer>(serviceProvider => new RetryEnabledErrorMessageSerializer<IMessageType>(givenSubscriptionId)));
```

And just implemented the Serialize method like so:

```
 public class RetryEnabledErrorMessageSerializer<T> : IErrorMessageSerializer where T : class, IMessageType
 {
        public string Serialize(byte[] messageBody)
        {
             string stringifiedMsgBody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(messageBody);
             var objectifiedMsgBody = JObject.Parse(stringifiedMsgBody);

             // Add/update RetryInformation into objectifiedMsgBody here
             // I have a dictionary that saves <key:consumerId, val: TryInfoObj>

             return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectifiedMsgBody);
        }
  }
```

The actual retrying is done by a simple console app/windows service periodically via the EasyNetQ Management API:

```
            var client = new ManagementClient(AppConfig.BaseAddress, AppConfig.RabbitUsername, AppConfig.RabbitPassword);
            var vhost = client.GetVhostAsync("/").Result;
            var aliveRes = client.IsAliveAsync(vhost).Result;
            var errQueue = client.GetQueueAsync(Constants.EasyNetQErrorQueueName, vhost).Result;
            var crit = new GetMessagesCriteria(long.MaxValue, Ackmodes.ack_requeue_false);
            var errMsgs = client.GetMessagesFromQueueAsync(errQueue, crit).Result;
            foreach (var errMsg in errMsgs)
            {
                var innerMsg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Error>(errMsg.Payload);
                var pubInfo = new PublishInfo(innerMsg.RoutingKey, innerMsg.Message);
                pubInfo.Properties.Add("type", innerMsg.BasicProperties.Type);
                pubInfo.Properties.Add("correlation_id", innerMsg.BasicProperties.CorrelationId);
                pubInfo.Properties.Add("delivery_mode", innerMsg.BasicProperties.DeliveryMode);
                var pubRes = client.PublishAsync(client.GetExchangeAsync(innerMsg.Exchange, vhost).Result,
                     pubInfo).Result;
            }
```

Whether retry is enabled or not is known by my consumer itself, giving it more control so it can choose to handle the retried msg or just ignore it. Once ignored, the msg will obviously not be tried again; that's how EasyNetQ works.